# Python main program exe uses subprocess.popen to call other program exes, if the value is passed to other programs exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote two programs in `python3` and packaged them as `exe` files, the main program and the subprograms. In the main program, I use the subprocess. open to calling the subprograms. How can I pass the values to the subprograms and the subprograms can receive them?
The problem comes from the program that I am making a tool manager, which is written in pyqt5. The exe programs managed in the manager are derived from programs developed by different people, so you need to pass values to these exe programs.

Comment: Hi 6fanfan6. There's a pretty clear direct answer to this using `sys.argv` or `os.environ`, which I'd be happy to write up, but this feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It isn't particularly normal for two python programs to share code by using separate exe files; you'd usually use `import` statements for this. Could you edit your question to tell us a bit more about your "real" problem, and why you're trying to solve it by using multiple executables?

Comment: The `subprocess` documentation covers how to pass arguments - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. You wrote "I wrote two programs...and packaged them as exe files", but later you wrote "The exe programs are...developed by different people". Are both programs written by you or not? If you control of both the manager program and the managed programs, could you clarify why using `import` is not appropriate? If you aren't in control of the managed programs, could you clarify how they expect to receive parameters?

Comment: Having a minimal example of the part of your code that uses `subprocess.open` and the part of the managed code that expects to receive values would really help clarify your question.

Comment: It is because there are many tools in the manager, some are developed by me and some are not developed by me, so this problem will be caused

Comment: @6fanfan6 Gotcha! Now it makes sense! Just one more question from me, I promise: How do the not-developed-by-you programs expect to receive values? Do you run them like `./not_my_program.exe value1=thing value2=other_thing`?

Comment: subprocess.call(not_my_program.exe value1=thing value2=other_thing)